# JS: Creating, adding and replacing items in an array via user input, outputting the list twice- before and after replacement

Tags: javascript, arrays

Coding in JS, specifically working on arrays in this task.

The purpose of this is to create a guest list, asking the user for 10 names to input.
Once 11 names have been input, the guestList must be output. THIS IS WORKING.

On the 11th entry, the program asks the user if they would like to replace someone on the list (with that 11th entry) (y/n).
I have created for the y/n option.

The program prompts the user who they want to replace, and they can insert their choice.

This is where I'm not sure how to fix this.

Once the user input who they want to replace, my program just keeps asking and asking and asking.
The list prints out every second time a name is then inserted, WITHOUT the replacement effected or terminating.

Here is my code below:

```js
let guestList = [];

while (guestList.length < 11) {
  let guestListQ = prompt("Please enter the names of the people you'd like to invite to your dinner party");
  if (guestList.length != 10) {
    guestList.push(guestListQ);
  } else if (guestList.length == 10) {
    console.log("You have already added 10 people to your guest list.");
    console.log(guestList);
    let replaceGuest = prompt("Would you like to replace someone on the list with this person? y/n").toUpperCase();

    if (replaceGuest == "Y") {
      let replaceName = prompt("Who would you like to replace? ");
      const newName = "";
      console.log(guestList.slice(newName));
      break;
    } else if (replaceGuest == "N") {
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(guestList);
```

The program needs to replace one of the first 10 names entered with the 11th name entered, and then console.log it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: I'm not getting the issue either with it continuously "asking" as you mentioned. This line `guestList.slice(newName)` isn't right though, what are you thinking this line will do? You might want to take a look at [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in the docs and see if its the right tool for this. You most likely instead want to use `.indexOf()`to find the index within your array of the name to replace and then use bracket notation (ie: `arr[i] = newVal`) to set that index to your new name.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that method.
The issue is that after it asks for which name I want to replace, it is meant to print the list out, with the change made.
But instead it keeps asking for another name and prints out the first list over and over.